# Why use Bonferroni approximation for experiment-wise alpha?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

It seems the Bonferroni method (dividing experimentwise alpha by # of comparisons) for choosing the p level to fix the experimentwise alpha (when doing many pairwise comparisons) is more conservative than just solving $1 - (1 - p)^k = .05$ to get the alpha to use for each of the $k$ pairwise comparisons.  Why not just solve the equation?

Comment: Also note that Bonferroni $\beta$ approaches Šidák one quite fast for large $k$ and small $p$ -- for $p$=1% both methods produce practically the same value.

Comment: @mbq, how did you get the accents on Sidak? Is that because you have a special keyboard? I didn't find any $\LaTeX$ when I right-clicked.

Comment: @gung Ctrl-C Ctrl-V -- the rest is an Unicode magic. You can also use appropriate keyboard layout or just some app showing special character palettes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Dunn-Sidak approach (your second equation) is only valid if your contrasts are *orthogonal*, whereas the Bonferroni adjustment is guaranteed to always hold your experimentwise alpha below your chosen value.  In addition, with only a few contrasts, both methods will yield almost identical values.  When combined with the fact that the Bonferroni adjustment is easier for many people to understand, remember, and calculate, those are the basic reasons for its prevalence.

Comment: What exactly does orthogonal mean in this context?

Comment: Adding to @gung's excellent answer. With k = 10, Dunn-Sidak, by my calculations, gives 0.0052 and Bonferroni gives .005.

Comment: @Alexander, try [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_%28statistics%29); if that's not what you're asking, ping me again with more info.

Comment: The linked Wikipedia page confuses "orthogonal" and "independent": "Because orthogonal contrasts test different aspects of the data, they are independent" (Wikipedia). However, orthogonality is a relationship between vectors, e.g., coefficient vectors of contrasts (-> dot product = 0). Independence is a relationship between random variables, e.g., test statistics. Having orthogonal contrasts does not automatically imply independent test statistics for those contrasts, since the test statistics share the same error estimate in the denominator.

Comment: @caracal, thanks for clearing that up. The part I care about is the dot product of the contrast weights equaling 0, but it's a bit to explain what's going on there & why it's important, so I figured the Wikipedia page would do. I didn't edit it, though (or perhaps read it thoroughly enough).

Answer (score 0):

Gung gave an excellent answer.  i just want to add that nothing is simpler than dividing alpha by n (the number of tests).  Although Bonferroni is conservative it is easy to use and does not require added assumptions as Sidak and others do.  Now it is bad when individual p-values are realtively large or n gets very large.  But when the raw p-values are small it works well adn the level of conservatism is minimal.

Comment: What do you mean by "bad"?

Answer (score 0):

According to Abdi (2007), the main reason is simply that Bonferroni was easier to calculate than Sidak in the old days.

**What the article may disagree with gung's answer** is that similar to Bonferroni, when the comparisons are dependent, Sidak also gives a lower bound.  Bonferroni is simply the first (linear) term of Taylor expansion of Sidak. Therefore, you can always use Sidak whether the comparisons are independent or not.

In modern days, Bonferroni is only preferred over Sidak because it is more familiar.

- Abdi, H. (2007). [The Bonferonni and Šidák Corrections for Multiple Comparisons](http://www.cogsci.ucsd.edu/~dgroppe/STATZ/Abdi-Bonferroni2007-pretty.pdf). *Encyclopedia of Measurement and Statistics*. Thousand Oaks (CA): Sage.

Comment: Thank you for this contribution. I don't doubt the point about the ease of calculation. The point that the Dunn-Sidak constitutes a lower bound is also a reasonable one. However, note that people usually want an *upper* bound on the type I error, not a lower bound, which may be part of the reason Bonferroni remains common nonetheless.

Comment: Hi gung, thank you for your reply.  I will discuss my understanding of Abdi's article (page 5-7), please let me know if I am wrong. The main idea is that alpha[PT]>=Sidak>=Bonferroni, where alpha[PT] is the ideal type 1 error per comparison corrected based on the desired family wise type 1 error.  When the comparisons are independent, alpha[PT]=Sidak.  When they are dependent, both Sidak and Bonferroni gives lower bound, therefore, they are considered "conservative".  Bonferroni is slightly more conservative than Sidak.  Let me know if I misunderstand something, thanks very much.

Comment: My understanding is that when the contrasts are not orthogonal the Bonferroni correction gives the *upper* bound & the Sidak gives the *lower* bound. Since people want to ensure that the FW type I error rate is not $>\alpha$, they often use B.

Comment: Yes, I think this is where you and the article may differ slightly.  Sidak correction, 1-(1-alpha[FT])^(1/C), can be expanded using Taylor Polynomial around 0 as alpha[FT]/C + (1/C)(1-1/C)[(1-ksi)^(1/C-2)](alpha[FT]^2)/2.  alpha[FT]/C is Bonferroni correction, the remainder term is positive in the interval [0,1), therefore 1-(1-alpha[FT])^(1/C)>=alpha[FT]/C, and Sidak>=Bonferroni.  According to this logic, if Sidak is a lower bound, Bonferroni must be a lower bound as well.  Thanks, this is an interesting discussion.  Sorry, I haven't learned how to type formula here yet.